# Visualizing the trajectory of a mass on top of a wedge on a frictionless tabletop

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, kinematics, visualization

*A wedge with mass M rests on a frictionless, horizontal tabletop. A block with mass m is placed on the wedge (Fig. 1). There is no friction between the block and the wedge. The system is released from rest.*

Question: **As seen by a stationary observer, what is the shape of the trajectory of the block?**

[image: Fig. 1]

The answer key states the shape is a spiral. I'm trying to visualize how this is possible, but I can't seem to wrap my head around it. I don't understand the shape or how it's meant to look across a timeline. **Thus my main issue is how do I create an equation to represent the x-position of the block, assuming our reference point was at x = 0?**

[image: Fig. 2]

In an effort to graph the trajectory, I created the above figure (*Fig. 2*). I calculated an equation for the acceleration of the block in both the x and y-direction.

$$a_x=\frac{gM}{\left(M+m\right)\tan\left(\alpha \right)+\left(\frac{M}{\tan\left(\alpha \right)}\right)}$$
$$a_y=\frac{-g\left(M+m\right)\tan\left(\alpha \right)}{\left(M+m\right)\tan\left(\alpha \right)+\left(\frac{M}{\tan\left(\alpha \right)}\right)}$$

Then I calculated the acceleration of the wedge in the horizontal direction, in order to ensure my center of mass was standstill. It was.

$$A=\frac{-gm}{\left(M+m\right)\tan\left(\alpha \right)+\left(\frac{M}{\tan\left(\alpha \right)}\right)}$$

At this point, I graphed the kinematic displacement equations using acceleration from mock values to receive the above graph. Unfortunately, it does not look like a spiral, making me even more confused, wondering if the equation I used for horizontal displacement is showing an incorrect graph.

The variables used for the graph above were, M = 1 kg, m = 10 kg, angle = 30°, initial block height = 200 m.

Comment: I'm very dubious about the spiral trajectory...the problem looks very 1D to me. How could you expect a spiral in this case?

Comment: @user8736288 The incline is free to move.

Comment: You have a constant acceleration, but the block's acceleration will not be constant.

Comment: @Paul Why not? It will be constant.

Comment: @DvijD.C. Sorry, I can't comment on deleted posts. Let $a_b$ be the acceleration of the block relative to the wedge, $a_p$ be the leftward acceleration of the wedge relative to the surface, $N$ be the normal force between the wedge and the block. Newton's Second Law gives three equations: $m(-a_p + a_b\cos\alpha) = N\sin\alpha$, $ma_b\sin\alpha = mg - N\cos\alpha$, and $Ma_p = N\sin\alpha$. The diminished normal force comes from the first equation, since $a_p$ is positive.

Comment: @gmz No, again, there is no place where you wrote down a single letter for either time or for the distance of the block from some point. Your equations are correct, I agree, but you solve them and you get a time-independent solution as time is nowhere to be found in your equations. Anyway, let's continue the discussion in a personal chat if you want to discuss further.

Comment: @DvijD.C. Oh, you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to physics SE! :) Your calculations seem about right, and regardless of the details of the calculation, the acceleration of the block will be constant as long as it has not left the wedge. The way to see this is to realize that the free body diagram of the system doesn't depend on where the block is on the wedge (again, as long as it is on the wedge) and thus, since none of the forces are velocity dependent or position-dependent (again, beyond their dependence on the fact that the block is on the wedge) your equations for acceleration won't depend on where the block is on the edge or on time.  And thus, the motion of the block would be a constant acceleration motion. There are only two options for the trajectory of a constant acceleration motion in a plane:

- It will be linear iff the object's initial velocity is zero or if its initial velocity is along the direction of acceleration (either parallel or anti-parallel).
- It will be parabolic iff the object's initial velocity is non-zero and not aligned with the direction of acceleration.

So, there is no way for the motion to be spiral.

Comment: Nope, the normal force from the wedge varies as the block moves down the plane.

Comment: @gmz There is no reason for that to be the case as far as I can see. What would change in your free body diagram (and consequently in your equations) depending on where the block is on the wedge as long as it is on the wedge? But I will delete the answer for now due to the resistance in the comments until I have time to do an explicit calculation.

Comment: @DvijD.C. As the wedge accelerates to the left, the normal force required to keep the block on the ramp lessens.

Comment: @gmz No, you are imagining a practical case where the wedge was held fixed and then was allowed to let go. In any case, regardless of where your intuition comes from, do you have mathematical reasoning to support your claim? As I said, I see no way for the "distance of block on wedge from the ground" to enter into equations of motion as is clear if you write down the free body diagrams.

Comment: I have undeleted the post as I think the reasoning is sufficient.

Comment: @ACB I can only address a claim if I know the claim, do you have some links?

Comment: I think this is a textbook problem. So if you just search for the problem statement, you can find some.

Comment: @ACB Yes, but I only follow reliable sources and none of them claim that the trajectory is spiral  Seriously tho, this is not "a textbook problem" but rather a whole big genre of textbook problems, so I honestly couldn't find any source that particularly discusses the trajectory w.r.t. ground in the case of a movable wedge. Moreover, _you_ made the positive claim that many sources claim that the spiral is the trajectory, so it would be incumbent upon you to give some examples for one to respond to.

Comment: @ACB I'm confused as to why you're telling other people to back up claims that *you* are making. I can't find anything about a spiral trajectory here. It would be so much easier for everyone involved if you just gave a source you are referring to.

Comment: Ok, I retracted my comment. But as your request here's one example I found. https://www.numerade.com/ask/question/moving-wedge-a-wedge-with-mass-m-rests-on-a-frictionless-horizontal-tabletop-a-block-with-mass-m-is-placed-on-the-wedge-there-is-no-friction-between-the-block-and-the-wedge-the-system-is-rel-56068/ but I don't know if this is correct.

Comment: @ACB Any link that doesn't ask for my credit card?

Comment: Sorry, does that ask for your credit cart? I didn't know that. However there is a video transcript. (Anyway don't mind this. Forget my previous comment(s)) : )